# A byte[] to byte* property

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a property that will make a pointer (byte*) from my byte array (byte[]), this does work, however whenever I modify this returned pointer, my byte array will not be modified, this is a piece of the code I want to use.

```
public unsafe class PacketWriter
{
    private readonly byte[] _packet; 
    private int _position;

    public byte* Pointer
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (byte* pointer = _packet)
                return pointer;
        }
    }

    public PacketWriter(int packetLength)
    {
      _packet = new byte[packetLength];   
    }

    //An example function
    public void WriteInt16(short value)
    {
        if (value > Int16.MaxValue)
            throw new Exception("PacketWriter: You cannot write " + value + " to a Int16.");
        *((short*)(Pointer + _position)) = (short) value;
        _position += 2;
    }

    //I would call this function to get the array.
    public byte[] GetPacket
    {
        get { return _packet; }
    }
}
```

Also, I realize I could simply remove the property and put the code inside the function, that would probably work, however I am trying to figure out a way to do it using that property - unless this decreases performance, in that case please let me know.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of simply using a normal array?

Comment: This code will bomb or silently corrupt the heap when the garbage collector moves the array.  The array isn't pinned anymore after the property getter returns.  Odds are low but not zero.

Comment: It just struck me that you're writing code that will likely be used for network communication, where you probably want to preserve network byte ordering.  In that case, I recommend using BinaryReader and BinaryWriter on a MemoryStream, as these let you specify the endian-ness of your encoding.  Both your proposed code and BitConverter will use the platform endian-ness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using pointers here (in C#) is pointless.

Note that if you replace the `Pointer` property with

```
public byte[] Data { get { return _packet; } }
```

You have a property that returns a *reference* to the byte array and it will let you do the same editing in the array as a pointer, without copying the array at any point.

And another piece of advice, in your Write16, use:

```
byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
data.CopyTo(_packet, _positiion);
_position += data.Length;
```

Comment: +1, BitConverter is the cleanest and most platform-safe way of writing byte equivalents to an array (it uses the platform endian-ness).

Answer (score 2):

When your control leaves `fixed` (and it does it right after return) your object is not pinned any more. So it is valid only inside `fixed`

Comment: @Andrey, Is there a different way to achieve my goal?

Comment: @Basser use C++ :) you should use `fixed` in scope of function. Property access will not work. i see no reason to use `byte*` here, pointers are exceptional in C# and require exceptional situations. This one is definitely not.

Comment: @Basser, what is your goal? What do you want to do with the pointer?

Comment: I am simply looking for the best performance to edit a byte array, and still be able to have some 'decent-looking' code

Comment: @Basser is editting byte array a bottleneck in your application? if no then forget about it. btw, arrays work very effectively in .net, i don't think that this will bring you boost.

Comment: @Andrey So you think I should simply write to the byte arrays, instead of using pointers?

Comment: @Basser yes, i do. follow the general rule: optimize code only when it is bottleneck. if you need to do hard calculations with pointers then it is good reason to think is .net an appropriate framework for your app.

Comment: Btw. in `public void WriteInt16(short value) { if (value > Int16.MaxValue) …` the condition is always false.

Answer (score 2):

Don't expose the pointers.
You're pre-emptively optimizing your code.
To give you an example, I wrote a PNG decoder in C# for a project I'm working on and rather than assume that the bottlenecks, I wrote the code to make managing data structures trivial and was fairly blithe about I/O and data movement.  In benchmarking the code, the bottlenecks were NOT in data movement or in I/O, but were in the Paeth predictor - computation that was being done on a per-pixel basis (details [here](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2010/02/23/libpng-you-re-doing-it-wrong.aspx)).

Write the code readable and maintainable first, then see where the bottlenecks are.  You can always refactor it later.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing into an array in .NET is extremely efficient; the jitter generates machine code that is essentially equivalent to access via pointer arithmetic.  If you write equivalent code that uses bit-masking and shifting to generate the byte values for writing to the array, it will probably be faster than this attempt at unsafe code.  The overhead of pinning is going to be much higher than a few cheap bit-masking operations.

If you really, absolutely need to save a few clock cycles (at the expensive cost of reduced maintainability), either create an unmanaged DLL in C++ to handle the high-performance requirements or write pure unsafe code operating purely on unmanaged memory with Marshal.  In fact, Marshal already has a [WriteInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43kt297w.aspx) method you can use.  The overhead of marshaling back to managed memory is going to be relatively high, however (much higher than the bit masking), so this is only beneficial if you're writing a very large amount of memory in an extremely inner loop and are doing other operations with it besides simply copying (since it will have to copy to managed memory to marshal, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with managed memory, then yes, you have to limit it to the `fixed` block.

BUt it seems that you are using a lot of pointer handling and my question is why do you need a managed memory? Just allocate some unmanaged memory using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` and then expose that as a pointer. You just need to make sure you are releasing it in a `Dispose()`.